# TDBChart Incorrect/Omitted X-Axis values

Tags: date, delphi, teechart

I'm displaying the the amount of people attending movie shows on the TDBChart the date of the show is the X-axis and the amount of people are the Y-axis. The split between different movies are represented by the stacked column.

I achieve this by creating a bar series(Created dynamically) for each movie. But when I display the data for more than two movies all the dates are not displayed on the X-axis, only the dates of the first series(movie) added. The further series are just squished into the first series' dates.

Here you see the chart for Princess Mononoke only, the dates are correct.
                                                                              The Date Range selectors don't do anything at the moment.
[image]

This is the chart for Reaper only, the dates are correct
[image]

But when you put them together Reapers data gets thrown into Princess Mononokes dates even though Reaper does not show on the dates of Princess Mononoke. And Reapers dates are completely omitted??. 
[image]

This is the code to add the series(Movies), I also dynamically create SQL querys for the series. qryStatMovieSelection is just all the movies that are selected.
I don't really know how to deal with this one, any ideas?

```
      DataModule1.qryStatMovieSelection.First;
      for iCount := 0 to iSelectedMovies - 1 do
      begin
        arrQryDateCustomers[iCount] := TADOQuery.Create(Self);
        With arrQryDateCustomers[iCount] do
        begin
          Connection := conCinema;
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add(
            'SELECT Movies.MovieID, Name, ShowDate,(SUM(NormalTickets) + SUM(ChildTickets) + SUM(SeniorTickets)) AS SeatsBooked');
          SQL.Add('FROM Movies, Invoice, Shows');
          SQL.Add('WHERE Invoice.ShowID = Shows.ShowID AND Shows.MovieID = Movies.MovieID');
          // MovieID in selected table
          SQL.Add('AND Movies.MovieID = '+ DataModule1.qryStatMovieSelection.FieldByName('MovieID').AsString);
          SQL.Add('GROUP BY Movies.MovieID, Name, ShowDate');
          Open;
        end;

        //create series
        arrBarSeriesMovies[iCount] := TBarSeries.Create(Self);
        With arrBarSeriesMovies[iCount] do
        begin
          ParentChart := crtStatistics;
          YValues.ValueSource := 'SeatsBooked';
          XValues.DateTime := True;
          XLabelsSource := 'ShowDate';
          DataSource := arrQryDateCustomers[iCount];
          MultiBar := mbStacked;
          Marks.Style := smsValue;
          Marks.ArrowLength := -20;
          Color := arrColor[iCount];
          Title := DataModule1.qryStatMovieSelection.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
          Active := True;
        end;
        DataModule1.qryStatMovieSelection.Next;
      end;
    end
```

Comment: You're probably looking for the `mbSideAll` style of the `MultiBar`.

Comment: Here's reverse engineered schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1d928/5 for those who want to play with your code.

Comment: It's not mbSideAll, I want the bars to stack, but only if their dates are the same. Otherwise they form another bar with their own date.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to stack Bars with the same date, even if they don't coincide in time.

The problem is the `TBarSeries` stacks the bars that coincide in `ValueIndex`, not in `XValue`. So you should add a Null point in the series that has no tickets sold for a date to have the same number of points in both series.

First of all, I initialized the data as follows:

```
type TShow = class
  ShowDate: TDateTime;
  TotalTickets: Integer;
end;

type TMovie = class
  Title: String;
  Shows: array of TShow;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);    
var movies: array of TMovie;
begin
  SetLength(movies, 2);
  movies[0]:=TMovie.Create;
  movies[1]:=TMovie.Create;

  with movies[0] do
  begin
    Title:='Princess Mononoke';
    SetLength(Shows, 2);
    Shows[0]:=TShow.Create;
    Shows[1]:=TShow.Create;

    Shows[0].ShowDate:=StrToDateTime('14/07/2017 15:00');
    Shows[0].TotalTickets:=19;
    Shows[1].ShowDate:=StrToDateTime('20/07/2017 17:30');
    Shows[1].TotalTickets:=5;
  end;

  with movies[1] do
  begin
    Title:='Reaper';
    SetLength(Shows, 2);
    Shows[0]:=TShow.Create;
    Shows[1]:=TShow.Create;

    Shows[0].ShowDate:=StrToDateTime('20/07/2017 15:30');
    Shows[0].TotalTickets:=1;
    Shows[1].ShowDate:=StrToDateTime('23/07/2017 17:30');
    Shows[1].TotalTickets:=15;
  end;
end;
```

Then I calculate the min and max dates for the given movies with this function:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);    

  procedure MinMaxDates(AMovies: array of TMovie; var MinDate: TDateTime; var MaxDate: TDateTime);
  var i, j: Integer;
  begin
    MinDate:=Trunc(AMovies[0].Shows[0].ShowDate);
    MaxDate:=Trunc(AMovies[0].Shows[0].ShowDate);
    for i:=0 to High(AMovies) do
      for j:=0 to High(AMovies[i].Shows) do
      begin
        MinDate:=Min(MinDate, Trunc(AMovies[i].Shows[j].ShowDate));
        MaxDate:=Max(MinDate, Trunc(AMovies[i].Shows[j].ShowDate));
      end;
  end;

var movies: array of TMovie;
    minDate, maxDate: TDateTime;
begin
  // Data initialization here

  MinMaxDates(movies, minDate, maxDate);
```

Now I can think on several options here.

**Option 1**: You can add points at all the series at all the dates between `minDate` and `maxDate`, even when no tickets are sold. This option respects a proportion in the distance between the bars and gives thin bars:

[image: Option 1]

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);    

  function TicketsAtDate(AMovie: TMovie; ADate: TDateTime): Integer;
  var i: Integer;
  begin
    Result:=0;
    for i:=0 to High(AMovie.Shows) do
      if Trunc(AMovie.Shows[i].ShowDate) = ADate then
      begin
        Result:=AMovie.Shows[i].TotalTickets;
        Break;
      end;
  end;

var i, j: Integer;
    movies: array of TMovie;
    minDate, maxDate: TDateTime;
begin
  // Data initialization here

  MinMaxDates(movies, minDate, maxDate);

  for i:=0 to High(movies) do
  begin
    //create series
    With Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
    begin
      XValues.DateTime := True;
      MultiBar := mbStacked;
      Marks.Style := smsValue;
      Marks.ArrowLength := -20;
      Title:=movies[i].Title;
      j:=0;
      while (minDate+j<=maxDate) do
      begin
        AddXY(minDate+j, TicketsAtDate(movies[i], minDate+j));

        if YValue[Count-1] = 0 then
           SetNull(Count-1);

        Inc(j);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

**Option 2**: You can add points only when there's some ticket sold at every date. This option still respects a proportion in the distance between the bars and gives wide bars:

[image: Option 2]

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);    

  function AnyTicketSold(AMovies: array of TMovie; ADate: TDateTime): Boolean;
  var i, j: Integer;
  begin
    Result:=False;
    for i:=0 to High(AMovies) do
      for j:=0 to High(AMovies[i].Shows) do
        if (Trunc(AMovies[i].Shows[j].ShowDate) = ADate) and (AMovies[i].Shows[j].TotalTickets > 0) then
        begin
          Result:=True;
          Exit;
        end;
  end;

var i, j: Integer;
    movies: array of TMovie;
    minDate, maxDate: TDateTime;
begin
  // Data initialization here

  MinMaxDates(movies, minDate, maxDate);

  for i:=0 to High(movies) do
  begin
    //create series
    With Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
    begin
      XValues.DateTime := True;
      MultiBar := mbStacked;
      Marks.Style := smsValue;
      Marks.ArrowLength := -20;
      Title:=movies[i].Title;
      j:=0;
      while (minDate+j<=maxDate) do
      begin
        if anyTicketSold(movies, minDate+j) then
        begin
          AddXY(minDate+j, TicketsAtDate(movies[i], minDate+j));

          if YValue[Count-1] = 0 then
             SetNull(Count-1);
        end;

        Inc(j);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I actually came to this conclusion and figured out a solution using temp tables. When I'm back at my computer I'l post it to get your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out a way to do it with temp tables inserting null values as a spacer; pretty much like Yeray's answer just with temp tables. I'd be grateful if someone with more knowledge than myself could compare the two.

So I start by initializing the X-axis with the dates and all 0 values on the Y-axis(just to avoid 0 values as a date in some cases);

```
With qryStatDateInitialization do
      begin
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Add('SELECT DISTINCT ShowDate, 0 AS Blank');
        SQL.Add('FROM Shows');
        SQL.Add('WHERE MovieID IN (' + MovieIDs + ')');
        Open;
      end;

      SetLength(arrDates, 0);

      //Populate dates array
      qryStatDateInitialization.First;
      SetLength(arrDates, qryStatDateInitialization.RecordCount);
      for iCount := 0 to qryStatDateInitialization.RecordCount - 1 do
      begin
        arrDates[iCount] := qryStatDateInitialization.FieldByName('ShowDate').AsString;
        qryStatDateInitialization.Next;
      end;

      //Series to initialize dates on X-axis
      barSeries := TBarSeries.Create(Self);
      barSeries.ShowInLegend := False;
      barSeries.ParentChart := crtStatistics;
      barSeries.DataSource := qryStatDateInitialization;
      barSeries.YValues.ValueSource := 'Blank';
      barSeries.XLabelsSource := 'ShowDate';
      barSeries.Marks.Style := smsValue;
      barSeries.MultiBar := mbStacked;
      barSeries.Marks.Hide;
      barSeries.ColorEachPoint := True;
      barSeries.Active := True;
```

Next I create the temp tables(for each movie) and then insert 0 value records in the appropriate position. I use the ID field for this.

```
for iCount := 0 to iSelectedMovies - 1 do
      begin
        //Create table for movie
        With qryEdit do
        begin
          //Create show table with autonumer
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add('CREATE TABLE tempTShow'+IntToStr(iCount));
          SQL.Add('(ID COUNTER , Name string, ShowDate string, SeatsBooked string)');
          ExecSQL;
          //Add data to show table
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tempTShow'+IntToStr(iCount));
          SQL.Add('SELECT Name, ShowDate, SeatsBooked');
          SQL.Add('FROM (SELECT Name, ShowDate,(SUM(NormalTickets) + SUM(ChildTickets) + SUM(SeniorTickets)) AS SeatsBooked');
            SQL.Add('FROM Movies, Invoice, Shows');
            SQL.Add('WHERE Invoice.ShowID = Shows.ShowID AND Shows.MovieID = Movies.MovieID');
            SQL.Add('AND Movies.MovieID = ' + DataModule1.qryStatMovieSelection.FieldByName('MovieID').AsString);
            SQL.Add('GROUP BY Name, ShowDate');
            SQL.Add('ORDER BY ShowDate ASC)');
          ExecSQL;
          //Set autonumber to normal integer to set show positions accordingly
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add('ALTER TABLE tempTShow'+IntToStr(iCount));
          SQL.Add('ALTER COLUMN ID integer');
          ExecSQL;

          Inc(iTempTableCountInternal);
        end;

        qryStats.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tempTShow'+IntToStr(iCount);
        qryStats.Open;

        //Insert 0 value spacers in temp table
        iCountDateSort := 0;
        iDateOn := 0;
        While iDateOn < length(arrDates) - 1 do
        begin
          sDate := qryStats.FieldByName('ShowDate').AsString;
          if NOT (sDate = arrDates[iDateOn]) then
            With qryEdit do
            begin
              SQL.Clear;
              SQL.Add('UPDATE tempTShow'+IntToStr(iCount));
              SQL.Add('SET ID = (ID+1) WHERE ID >= ' + IntToStr(iCountDateSort+1));
              ExecSQL;

              SQL.Clear;
              SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tempTShow'+IntToStr(iCount));
              SQL.Add('(ID, Name, ShowDate, SeatsBooked) VALUES ('
                +IntToStr(iCountDateSort+1) + ',"0","0",0)' );
              ExecSQL;
            end
            else
            begin
              qryStats.Next;
              Inc(iCountDateSort);
              //iDateOn := iCountDateSort;
            end;
            Inc(iDateOn);
        end;
```

And then create the series with the temp table as data source and set 0 values to null

```
//Create query for series
            arrQrys[iCount] := TADOQuery.Create(Self);
            arrQrys[iCount].Connection := conCinema;
            arrQrys[iCount].SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tempTShow'+IntToStr(iCount)+' ORDER BY ID';
            arrQrys[iCount].Open;

        // create series
        arrBarSeries[iCount] := TBarSeries.Create(Self);
        With arrBarSeries[iCount] do
        begin
          ParentChart := crtStatistics;

          YValues.ValueSource := 'SeatsBooked';
          arrBarSeries[iCount].
          XValues.DateTime := True;
          XLabelsSource := 'ShowDate';
          DataSource := arrQrys[iCount];
          MultiBar := mbStacked;
          Marks.Style := smsValue;
          Marks.ArrowLength := -20;
          Color := arrColor[iCount];
          Title := DataModule1.qryStatMovieSelection.FieldByName('Name')
            .AsString;
          Active := True;

          for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
          begin
            if YValue[i-1] = 0 then
              SetNull(i-1);
          end;
        end;
```